# How to limit 1 request at a time per client?

Tags: nginx, throttling

Unlike `ngx_http_limit_req_module`, I'm looking for a way to limit 1 request at a time per IP. In other words, if the previous request hasn't been responded to yet by the upstream application server, Nginx should 444 or 429 any further requests.

1. Intuition says that this would save memory compared to `ngx_http_limit_req_module` since there are no counters to increment.
2. Under certain circumstance (ex. bots, brute-force attacks, etc.), the upstream application server may choose to deliberately hold the request for a penalty of eg. 10 seconds or 10 minutes - but if Nginx still allows users to make requests in parallel, then the penalty is simply a wall that attackers can walk around.

Comment: You must not do it. Simple reason is behind a public IP there can be a huge network of NATted systems.

Comment: @user902384 It's good enough for my purposes. If it isn't, I'll find another way later. But I still want to try it. Besides, ngx_http_limit_req_module also throttles based on IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [ngx_http_limit_conn](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_conn_module.html)

but due of NAT usage in almost all ISP in the world you may face some problem